# Show that $\frac{2}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)\leq\sup_{x>0}|\frac{\sin (ax)}{ax}-\frac{\sin (bx)}{bx}|\leq 4\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inequality

Exercise:

> Let $a~,~b$ be a real number such that : $b>a>0$ then prove that
> $$\frac{2}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)\leq\sup_{x>0}|\frac{\sin (ax)}{ax}-\frac{\sin (bx)}{bx}|\leq 4\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right).$$

---

I was trying to study the function

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin (ax)}{ax}-\frac{\sin (bx)}{bx}.$$
But no results!
I need just an idea or ideas to start solving this impressive problem.

Comment: A sharper bound was recently proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4416911/42969

Comment: Where does the problem come from? It was also asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4420626/42969, so this is the third time in one week that this comes up.